# "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified" error when running insert query from ASP page

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, detailsview

I am trying to use an ASP detailsview to pass variables to an MSSQL stored procedure that then inserts values into multiple tables. The stored procedure works perfectly when I run it in SQL Management Studio. I have all of the stored procedure's variables set as parameters, yet I am still getting an error (below) when my ASP page runs. My ASP code and stored procedure are also included below the error message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This problem is starting to get extremely frustrating.

**Error Message:**

```
Server Error in '/PrinterUsage' Application.

Procedure or function Add_Count_By_Name has too many arguments specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web                 request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it         originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function     Add_Count_By_Name has too many arguments specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.     Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function Add_Count_By_Name has too many arguments specified.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1950522
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4856715
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,     SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1121
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +200
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +175
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +386
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +227
System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +86
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleInsert(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation) +274
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +676
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +113
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +118
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +135
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

**ASP code:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddCount.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddCountClass" Theme="ThemeMain" %>
```

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="NewCount_DS" Runat="server" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PrinterUsageConnectionString %>"
    DataSourceMode="DataReader"
    InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="Add_Count_By_Name" 
    DeleteCommand="Add_Count_By_ID" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    SelectCommand="Get_Count_By_PrinterID" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    UpdateCommand="Edit_Count_By_ID" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="pName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="dMonth" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="dYear" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:parameter Name="count" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:parameter Name="dID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:parameter Name="prevMonth_dID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:parameter Name="pID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="monthUsage" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="pName_DS" runat="server" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PrinterUsageConnectionString %>"
DataSourceMode="DataReader" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="Get_pNames" />

    <asp:DetailsView ID="AddPrinter_DV" runat="server" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True"
        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="NewCount_DS" 
        EnableModelValidation="True" DefaultMode="Insert" SkinID="detailsviewSkin" >

        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Printer Name:" SortExpression="pName" >
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="pNameDropdown" runat="server" DataSourceID="pName_DS"
                        DataValueField="pName" DataTextField="pName" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dMonth" HeaderText="Month" 
                SortExpression="dMonth"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dYear" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="dYear" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="countYtD" HeaderText="Count" 
                SortExpression="countYtD" />
        </Fields>

     </asp:DetailsView>

</asp:Content>
```

**SQL Stored Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_Count_By_Name]
--Declare variables
@pName NVARCHAR(100), @dMonth INT, @dYear INT, @count INT, 
@dID INT, @prevMonth_dID INT, @pID INT, @monthUsage INT
AS
BEGIN
--set variables
SET @dID = NULL
SET @prevMonth_dID = NULL
SET @pID = NULL
SET @monthUsage = NULL
--check if the printer has been added to the system
--if the printer is in the system, then save the pID to @pID
--if the printer is not in the system, display error msg and stop stored procedure
IF EXISTS (SELECT pID FROM PrinterTbl WHERE pName=@pName)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pID = pID FROM PrinterTbl WHERE pName=@pName;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Printer name not found. Please verify that the printer has been added to the system';
        RETURN 1;
    END

--Check if the date has been added to the system
--if date is in the system, save dID to @dID
--if date is not in the system, add it to the system
IF EXISTS (SELECT dId FROM DatesTbl WHERE dMonth=@dMonth AND dYear=@dYear)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @dID = dId FROM DatesTbl WHERE dMonth=@dMonth AND dYear=@dYear;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO DatesTbl (dMonth, dYear)
        VALUES (@dMonth, @dYear);
        SELECT @dID = dId FROM DatesTbl WHERE dMonth=@dMonth AND dYear=@dYear;
    END

--Verify that neither @pID or @dID contain a null value,
--then calculate the monthly usage and add the new count to CountTbl
IF @pID IS NOT NULL AND @dID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        --if the count is being added for January, manually set the month to December
        --and subtract 1 from the year to obtain dID of December of the previous year.
        --if adding a count for any month other than January, subtract 1 from @dMonth
        --to obtain @prevMonth_dID
        IF @dMonth = 1
            BEGIN
                SELECT @prevMonth_dID = dID FROM DatesTbl WHERE dMonth=12 AND dYear=(@dYear-1);
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @prevMonth_dID = (@dID-1);
            END
        --subtract the countYtd value from the previous month from the newly entered YtD count
        --to obtain the monthly usage for the printer.
        SELECT @monthUsage = @count - (SELECT countYtD FROM CountTbl WHERE dID = @prevMonth_dID);

        --insert the new count record into CountTbl
        INSERT INTO CountTbl (pID, dID, monthUsage, countYtD)
        VALUES (@pID, @dID, @monthUsage, @count);
    END
END
```

Comment: Could you run the query while tracing with the SQL Server Profiler so one could se what's actually passed to SQL Server?

Comment: Are you able to use SQL Server Profiler?  You might see what code is getting sent to the server itself; that might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I'm shooting in the dark here, but is this field causing the problems?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="countYtD" HeaderText="Count" 
        SortExpression="countYtD" />
```

The DataSource has `count` as a parameter, and so does the stored procedure.  The `countYtD` field doesn't exist, so I think that would be added automatically because it's a Bound Field.

Comment: Please be sure to accept one of the correct answers.  @AdrianIftode submitted the answer first, so I recommend accepting his so he gets the credit.

Comment: wow, i feel dumb. That was it. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 7):

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="countYtD" HeaderText="Count" 
                SortExpression="countYtD" />
```

This being a bound field, it will be added as a parameter to the stored procedure and does not belong to the parameters list. Try, if possible, transform it into a TemplateField and use `Eval` instead `Bind`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I experienced the same error while calling the Update Method of the data source for a gridview.

The data source called a stored procedure to perform the update to the database.

I corrected the problem this way:

First, make sure you declare all of your SP parameters in the  for the data source, include the DataKeys in the SP.

Second, all of the fields that you want to edit are bound using `<%# Bind("some Field") %>`.
DO NOT bind any other fields from the `SELECT` command.  Use `EVAL()` instead.

Third, the names of `UPDATE` Parameters MUST MATCH the names of any `BIND()` values. AND ALL update parameters must be BOUND to a input control (textbox, etc).

When the Data Source `Update()` method is called, it will parse the postback data and look for all `BIND()` values. These values MUST match the NAMES defined in the Update Parameters definitions.

For example, I have an   Column. It has both an `<ItemTemplate>` and  `<EditItemTemplate>` definition. In the `<ItemTemplate>`, I `Eval()` the SELECTED column Name,

```
 <ItemTemplate> <%# Eval("LastName") %> </ItemTemplate>
```

In the `<EditTemplate>`, I have declared a `<asp:textbox>` control to receive the value of the "FirstName" value from the SELECT Command.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="tbFirstName" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:textbox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

In the data source UPDATE paramaters, I defined this parameter

```
<UpdateParameters>
   <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" DbType="String" DefaultValue="" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Now, when the page posts back, the page will be parsed and the values for all of the `UPDATE` paramaters will be supplied from the controls whose values were `BIND()` with the same name of the `UPDATE` parameter.

Any mismatch in either spelling of parameter names, or any EXTRA `BIND()`'s for values NOT included in the `UPDATE` parameters will throw the  "Too Many Parameters" error.